# How to get what's in datatable where exist in another datatable by LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

If i have two datatables like this :

```
dt1

emp_num name  status

    1    aa    1

    2    bb    1

    3    cc    2
```

---

```
dt2


emp_num name  dep_code

 1      aa       536

 2      bb       782

 4      yuw      21

 5      rr       892
```

How to get what in the `dt1` and must exist in `dt2` and put the result in another `datatable`

The result :

```
emp_num name  status

 1      aa    1

 2      bb    1
```

Comment: RTFM [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq

```
var result = (from a in dt1.Rows
             join b in dt2.Rows
             on dt1.Rows["emp_num"]==dt2.Rows["emp_num"]
             select a).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Answer (score 1):

using LINQ join

```
var results = (from employees1 in db.dt1
               join employees2 in db.dt2 on employees1.emp_num  equals employees2.emp_num  
               where employees1.emp_num   == employees2.emp_num  
               select employees1);
```

Or you can just select whatever else you want.

The `var` will be an `IENumerable` list of whatever object type the result corresponds to. `db` above refers to your `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var List = (from a in context.dt1 
           join b in context.dt2 on a.emp_num equals b.emp_num

           select new
           {
              //Select your desired fields here
           }).ToList();
```